# Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: java, mysql, mysql-error-1064

public class Main{

```
private static boolean connectedToDatabase = false;
public static  String TableSchedule = "CREATE TABLE Schedule(\n"
        + " courseID CHAR(12) NOT NULL UNIQUE,\n"
        + " sectionNumber CHAR(18),\n"
        + " title VARCHAR(64),\n"
        + " year INT,\n"
        + " semester CHAR(6),\n"
        + " instructor VARCHAR(24),\n"
        + " department CHAR(16),\n"
        + " program VARCHAR(48),\n"
        + " PRIMARY KEY(courseID, sectionNUmber)\n"
        + ")";

static Connection connection;
static ResultSet resultS;
static PreparedStatement pStatement;

public static void main(String [] args) throws SQLException{
    
    connectToDatabase();
}
```

public static void connectToDatabase() throws SQLException{

```
    final String DATABASE_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/studentDB";
    final String USERNAME = "root";
    final String PASSWORD = "myPassword";
    
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DATABASE_URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
    connectedToDatabase = true;
    
    setQuery(TableSchedule);
```

}

public static void setQuery(String query) throws SQLException, IllegalStateException{

```
    if(!connectedToDatabase){
        throw new IllegalStateException("Not connected to Database");
    }
    
    pStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
    pStatement.executeUpdate("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TableSchedule);
    resultS = pStatement.executeQuery();
    
}
```

}

Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE Schedule(
courseID CHAR(12) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
sectionNumber CHAR(1' at line 1
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdateInternal(StatementImpl.java:1333)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeLargeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:2106)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1243)
at application.Main.setQuery(Main.java:53)
at application.Main.connectToDatabase(Main.java:42)
at application.Main.main(Main.java:30)

I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong here

Comment: Please post your query as text not image.Thanks

Comment: Try removing \n from your query

Comment: still the same error.

Comment: `TableSchedule` is your `CREATE TABLE` statement. You seem to be gluing `"DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "` onto the front and expecting that to be an executable statement.

Comment: `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS CREATE TABLE ` is not a valid SQL statement

Comment: whenever I remove the "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" part, it gives me an error of "table already exists" so that why I put the "drop table" part.

Comment: Dropping a table is a separate statement from creating a table. You can't just glue `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS` on the front of another statement.

Comment: You only need to create the table once. You don't need to keep executing a CREATE TABLE statement every time you use the table; and you probably don't need to keep dropping it and creating it again. It is not clear what you're hoping to achieve.

Comment: is there a way to create a table every time I run the code?

Comment: .... If you really want to drop and recreate the table every time, then execute a drop statement first, and then execute the create statement.

Comment: what I was trying is every time I run the java application, the already existed tables are dropped and new tables will be created

Comment: The statement to drop your Schedule table if it exists would be `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Schedule`. That's a separate statement from your `CREATE TABLE` statement.

Comment: got it to work now  - I'm so dumb that I'm creating the tables first and then dropping it.

Answer (score 0):

The statement you are executing here

```java
pStatement.executeUpdate("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TableSchedule);
```

is

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS CREATE TABLE Schedule (
etc.
```

That does not make sense as an SQL statement. Dropping a table and creating a table are separate statements.

To drop the table, if it exists, would be like this:

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Schedule
```

Then after executing that, you can execute the statement to recreate it, if that's really the way you want this to work.

Answer (score 0):

execute() : The method used for all types of SQL statements

executeUpdate() : This method is used for execution of DML statement(INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE)

executeQuery() : This method is used to retrieve data from database using SELECT query.

So here you need to use "executeUpdate()"
and also you need to execute the update for drop and update seperately

Dear observe the following lines in your code

```
pStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
pStatement.executeUpdate("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TableSchedule);
resultS = pStatement.executeQuery();
```

replace it with these lines

```
pStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
pStatement.executeUpdate("Drop Table if Exists Schedule");
pStatement.executeUpdate(query);
```

then run the program i hope it will solve your problem